# ASP.NET MVC Create View for ManyToMany relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking into creating Create method (within controller that view obviously uses) in which I'll be able to choose one or more "Bands" that are performers in certain music videos - "Vids". Ideally I would like it to work like tags bar here on Stack:

[image]

So I could type in bands' name and little dropdown menu could've suggest exact name that I could then add to the bar and then later on - submit.

My problem is - I have little to no idea how should I start with that. I started my project with dividing it's contents into 3 parts, Model with Entities and IdentityContext, Repository part and an actual app part.

My VM looks like that:

```
public class VidCreateViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Band> Bands { get; set; }
}
```

My Create methods within VidsController looks like that:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(VidCreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var vid = new Vid();
        vid.Title = model.Title;
        vid.Link = model.Link;
        vid.Bands = model.Bands;

        var result = await _vidRepository.SaveVidAsync(vid);
        if (!result)
            return View("Error");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

So my problem is on how to manage that kind of input form in the actual view, so it would suggest Bands from Band entity and then bind it within database, so certain video could have many performers and many bands could perform in music videos.

Comment: Check this: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Comment: That solves an actual implementation in the front, but my problem is more backend related. I don't know how to populate that list with Bands from another entity and then bind it within database so given bands will be performing in certain videos.

Comment: You'll need a collection of AllBands that you can add to your ViewModel (or ViewBag) and populate in the Create GET. You'll need to repopulate on model errors.